# Why does the Multiprocessing Pool method raise a TimeoutError?

Tags: python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

I'm using this as an example code and it gets frozen. I've opened the task manager and looked at the allocated resources. I can see a change in the number of processes before and after I run the code, but I cannot understand why it causes the console to freeze.
This happens only in Spyder. If I call the script from command line, it runs as it should.

```
import multiprocessing as mp
def doubler(number):
   return number*2
if __name__=='__main__':    
    pool=mp.Pool(processes=3)
    arglist=[1,2,3]
    result=[pool.apply_async(doubler,(i,)) for i in arglist]
    for res in result:
        print(res.get())
```

I've also used the example code from [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers) and it raises a TimeoutError without any description.
Screenshot:[TimeoutError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dpOwY.png)

Comment: Also, I should mention the code you've posted here isn't the same as the code you ran.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots or links to screenshots of text. Directly include it in your question.

Comment: @coldspeed The code I ran was in the link I pointed to below the code I posted here. Both the codes run in a separate python console, but raise an error in Spyder.

Comment: @mata duly noted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be running this in an interactive interpreter on windows.

There is [a note about that](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers) in the documentation:

> **Note**:
>   Functionality within this package requires that the `__main__` module be importable by the children. This is covered in Programming guidelines however it is worth pointing out here. This means that some examples, such as the `multiprocessing.pool.Pool` examples *will not work in the interactive interpreter*.

While it can work in some cases (if the OS supports `fork()` so multiprocessing can use the `fork` [start method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.get_start_method), but Windows does not), it is better to adhere to that recommendation.